# Can't publish asp.net 5 application after update to beta8 - the dependency ... could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, publish, asp.net-core, beta

I have updated a webApi asp.net5 application to beta8 and can't publish to the file system any more.

The build seems to work, i can debug and run the app, but if i try to publish i get errors like this...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(156,5): Error : Build failed.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(11,20): Error NU1001: The dependency AntiXSS >= 4.2.1 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(12,24): Error NU1001: The dependency Devshed.Csv >= 1.3.8 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(13,27): Error NU1001: The dependency Devshed.Shared >= 1.3.7 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(14,22): Error NU1001: The dependency DotNetZip >= 1.9.2 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(15,29): Error NU1001: The dependency Iesi.Collections >= 3.2.0.4000 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(16,25): Error NU1001: The dependency MongoDB.Bson >= 2.0.0 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(17,27): Error NU1001: The dependency MongoDB.Driver >= 2.0.0 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(18,32): Error NU1001: The dependency MongoDB.Driver.Core >= 2.0.0 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(19,23): Error NU1001: The dependency NHibernate >= 3.3.4.4000 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(20,17): Error NU1001: The dependency NLog >= 4.1.2 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(21,24): Error NU1001: The dependency NLog.Config >= 4.1.2 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(22,24): Error NU1001: The dependency NLog.Schema >= 4.0.1 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(23,31): Error NU1001: The dependency System.Data.SQLite >= 1.0.90 could not be resolved.
C:\Projekte\Workfolders\software\trunk\wrap\LibInternal.Database\project.json(24,24): Error NU1001: The dependency LibInternal >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(156,5): Error : Build failed.


3>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the Project.json file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "MongoDB.Driver": "2.0.1"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "LibInternal.Database": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

LibInternal.Database is a .NET Framework 4.5 Project.

Here is packages.config from LibInternal.Database:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Devshed.Csv" version="1.3.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Devshed.Shared" version="1.3.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="DotNetZip" version="1.9.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.2.0.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="3.3.4.4000" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog.Config" version="4.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog.Schema" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.90.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

And this is the .pubxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <CompileSource>False</CompileSource>
    <UsePowerShell>False</UsePowerShell>
    <WebRoot>wwwroot</WebRoot>
    <WwwRootOut>wwwroot</WwwRootOut>
    <IncludeSymbols>False</IncludeSymbols>
    <Native>False</Native>
    <IgnoreDNXRuntime>False</IgnoreDNXRuntime>
    <publishUrl>D:\Publish\WebAPI</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PublishDNXVersion>dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8</PublishDNXVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Somebody any ideas?

Comment: Did you update visual studio?
here link for it http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442

Comment: Yes, i did. I think there is no other way to install beta8.

Comment: Please share the project.json file

Comment: What dependencies does LibInternal.Database have?

Comment: Can you check your target DNX version while publishing. See if it is still pointing to beta 7?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of research and chat with microsoft developers i can say that is a bug.

This is a known issue by Microsoft team and hopefully it will be fixed in the next beta. I could fix this with this two steps:

In the solution folder should be a sub-folder named "wrap". In this folder are sub-folders with project.json files. In this file i had to change "net45" to "dnx451".

I had to change the name of the sub-folder in the bin folder:

\project\wrap{LibraryName}\bin\Release\net45 => \project\wrap{LibraryName}\bin\Release\dnx451

After that i could publish to filesystem.

Comment: Could you show the entire project.json,  also not clear which project.json you altered as each project has one.  I am running into this Issue on rc1-update1.  I can build/debug but not publish.

Comment: I have updated to rc1 update 1 and cant reproduce this error any more. Have you tried this? It was a known bug by microsoft. I think it was fixed.